# Overwriting a border on an image in Python PIL

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

I have a gallery application where the users upload photos and my code gives it a border, writes some of the photo attributes on the border and stores it.

```
image2 = Image.open('media/' + str(image.file))
width, height = image2.size;
image2 = ImageOps.expand(image2, border=(int(width/25),int(height/20),int(width/25),int(height/10)), fill='rgb(0,0,0)')
```

(Note that here my bottom border is longer than the top because I am writing attributes on the bottom border.)
Now I'm building an edit feature for the uploaded images where the user can change the attributes of the uploaded images. But the attributes that are already written on the border have to be overwritten.

So here, my approach is to put a black patch on the bottom border and re-write the new attributes without changes the top and side borders and without changing the aspect ratio. All of this has to be done using PIL.

Question is how do I put a black box on the bottom border?

I tried ImageOps.fit() as mentioned here https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.fit, but the aspect ratio doesn't seem to be right and I want to overwrite on the black border a black box and not crop the photo.

Comment: I recommend you to always keep original image in your DB in a separate field say `original` and when you are creating a new image with the border, save it in a different column say `edited`. so this way, when someone request with new attributes, use `original` image and edit it and update new image to `edited` column

Comment: Yeah, should have done that.

Comment: Apart from this, what else can I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems like the easiest solution is just quickly draw the black pixels in the area that you want using a couple loops and `Image.putpixel`

[image]

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('red.png')

for x in range(img.width):
    for y in range(img.height - 40, img.height):
        img.putpixel((x, y), (0, 0, 0))

img.save('red2.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way in my opinion is to create a new black image and paste onto your existing image -

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('test.png')
blackBox = Image.new(im.mode, (im.width, 50), '#000')
im.paste(blackBox, (0, im.height - blackBox.height))
```

Alternatively, you could use ImageDraw - http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/ImageDraw.html - which you could use to draw rectangles and other shapes.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
im = Image.open('test.png')
d = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
d.rectangle((0, im.height - 50, im.width, im.height), fill='#000')
```